# React Antd v4 autocomplete shows selected value instead of label upon selecting an option

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using React Antd v3 & upgrading it to v4, I noticed one issue, where the Autocomplete component was changed & now it is behaving in a weird manner

Passing a json array of `[{value: string, label: 123}]`, everything works well except that on value selection, the value is shown (not the label)

How to show the label instead & keep the value selected as the option value?

[Here is a link that shows the problem in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-shown-value-is-number-not-string-3lq2e)

[Another link where passing array of Options also doesn't work correctly](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-options-still-renders-number-not-label-rddeb)

Note:

It was working well in Ant v3, [as shown in this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-v3-autocomplete-works-well-swtkg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated [in the issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21882) that I have opened on Antd repo, this behaviour is intended in the new version

However, the closest thing to what I needed is the [Antd Select with a search](https://codesandbox.io/s/gxm0f) option, which does exactly what was needed in my question without any hacks

Answer (score 16):

You can use `key` attribute to pass unique Id, and use `value` as label. And then, use 2 parameters in your `onSelect` function to retrieve the key or any other attributes.

The first parameter is used to pass the value, and 

the second one is used to pass the object of the selected option.

Example data options:

```
const dataSource = [
  { key: 1, value: "John Doe"},
  { key: 2, value: "Jane Doe"}
]
```

Example field:

```
<AutoComplete
   options={options}
   onSelect={(val, option) => onSelect(val, option)}
   onSearch={onSearch}
>
   <Input.Search size="large" />
</AutoComplete>
```

Full code example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-liskov-t3l3j)

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/#components-auto-complete-demo-basic

it's intented to use value when it's uncontrolled and passing options in. if you want the label to be different than the actual value, you have to use

`const { Option } = AutoComplete;`

and pass the array of Option into Autocomplete's Children

```
<AutoComplete style={{ width: 200 }} onSearch={handleSearch} placeholder="input here">
   <Option value="111">Hello</Option>
</AutoComplete>
```

see https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/#components-auto-complete-demo-options